# Ruby on Rails - Currency : commas causing an issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal, numbers, currency

Looking on SO, I see that the preferred way to currency using RoR is using decimal(8,2) and to output them using number_to_currency();

I can get my numbers out of the DB, but I'm having issues on getting them in.

Inside my update action I have the following line:

```
if @non_labor_expense.update_attributes(params[:non_labor_expense]) 
puts YAML::dump(params)
```

The dump of params shows the correct value. xx,yyy.zz , but what gets stored in the DB is only xx.00

What do I need to do in order to take into account that there may be commas and a user may not enter .zz (the cents).  Some regex and for comma? how would you handle the decimal if it were .2 versus .20 .

There has to be a builtin or at least a better way.

My Migration (I don't know if this helps):

```
class ChangeExpenseToDec < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
       change_column :non_labor_expenses, :amount, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    end

    def self.down
          change_column :non_labor_expenses, :amount, :integer
    end
end
```

Comment: .2 and .20 are the same number, so it shouldn't matter how you store it, just how you display it.

Comment: Right. The first issue is that I lose the data after the comma. You are saying that once, I resolve that, the .2 and .20 will resolve itself on how it's stored in the DB?

Comment: See my answer; basically, you store the number in the database as a straight (unformatted) decimal number, and then format it as you'd like when you need to display it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might depend on what DBMS you're using, but as far as I know, decimal fields won't accept commas (at least not as separators; there might be a way to have the database accept a comma as a decimal point rather than a period). What you will have to do is remove the commas from your numbers (in a `before_save` or `before_validation` filter, perhaps), and then when you display the number, add the commas back in.

```
before_validation :strip_commas_from_non_labor_expense

def strip_commas_from_non_labor_expense
  self.non_labor_expense = self.non_labor_expense.to_s.gsub(/,/, '').to_f
end
```

Then use [`number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001684) when you want to display the expense amount formatted with comma separated groups and two decimal places, as you mentioned:

```
<%
  non_labor_expense = ... # get value from your model
  puts number_to_currency(non_labor_expense, :precision => 2, :separator => ',')
%>
```

Comment: I tried your before_validation and the function in the model, and I puts YAML::dump(self.amount) but the amount is already truncated. 

I get the following error: private method `gsub!' called for #<BigDecimal:7bf69fc,'0.22E2',4(8)> when I change your code to: self.amount.gsub!('/,/', '')

Any ideas?

Comment: If I do self.amount.to_s.gsub!('/,/', '') then gsub! works, but doing a dump before I make that call, it appears as if the value is already truncated. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. The quotes are not needed around the regular expression (I'm in PHP mode today, heh) and `gsub` should be used rather than `gsub!` because the latter replaces the string with `nil` if no replace was made. Also, I added `to_f` at the end to put it back into a float.

Comment: I experienced that this cut of the decimal values.

Answer (score 8):

I tried Daniel's before_validation idea and I just couldn't get it to work. It seemed that the by the time I get to the before_validation the input has already been converted. The solution I went with was to override the method for the column, and strip the commas there:

```
def profit=(num)
  num.gsub!(',','') if num.is_a?(String)
  self[:profit] = num
end
```

Comment: Works, but Henning's suggestion is DRY'er if you intend to convert , to . for several inputs in the app.

Comment: That works, you could also hook into the `attribute_before_type_cast` in your before_validation callback, e.g. `self.profit = profit_before_type_cast.to_s.gsub(/,/,'')`

Comment: This is a life saving answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the delocalize gem:

http://github.com/clemens/delocalize

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a code snippet that will make any decimal column accept values with the comma as decimal separator:

http://gem-session.com/2010/03/how-to-use-the-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-rails-activerecord-columns-and-text-fields

Comment: Linked moved : http://blog.makandra.com/2010/03/how-to-use-the-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-activerecord-columns-and-text-fields/